# Diferença entre e uso de "Boa!" e "Bom!" como interjeições

Tags: uso-de-palavras, concordância, sinônimos, interjeições

Qual é a diferença entre as interjeições "Boa!" e "Bom!"? As definições que encontrei no dicionário Priberam são quase iguais:

> ### [boa](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/boa)
>
> - *interjeição*
>   [Informal] Expressão designativa de aprovação, admiração ou ironia.
>
> ### [bom](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/bom)
>
> - *interjeição*
>    Expressão designativa de admiração, aprovação, etc.

Como saber quando se deve usar uma ou a outra? Depende no sexo de um(a) referente? E se for, qual referente?

Sempre ouvi "Boa!" como sinónimo de "Bem feito!" e fiquei curioso porque escolher "boa" em vez de "bom" ou "bem".

(Já sei que as palavras "boa" e "bom" têm muitos outros usos, mas estou a perguntar somente sobre os usos acima—quando usadas como interjeições de aprovação ou similar.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O significado que o Priberam dá para "bom!" não corresponde também à minha experiência. Parece-me mais parecido a "bem".

Comecemos por boa:

> (1) *- Acabei agora mesmo o trabalho. - Boa! Podes começar o seguinte.* (aprovação)
>   (2) *- Boa! Como é que conseguiste acabar isso em tão pouco tempo?!* (admiração/aprovação)
>   (3) *- Boa! Agora vamos ter de limpar esta merda toda!* (irónico)

"Bom" não pode substituir "boa" nas frases acima. Quando muito poderia substituir-se por "muito bom", tal como no [exemplo que o Aulete dá](http://www.aulete.com.br/bom):

> (4) *Muito bom! Sua intervenção foi perfeita!*

Só por si, é sinónimo de "bem". Citando o Aulete:

> **22** Us. quando se quer encerrar um assunto ou introduzir outro; BEM: *Bom, agora chega de conversa.*

Eu acrescentaria que há contudo mais significados:

> (5) *Pensei: bom, se calhar agora deu-lhe para a religião.*
>   (6) *Bom, agora deu-te para a religião ou quê.*
>   (7) *A vida é assim... bom, até é bastante positiva.*
>   (8) *Bom, bom, vamos dar início à aula.*
>   (9) *- Não tenho rosmaninho. - Bom, podes usar antes alecrim.*

Relacionados com o significado de 22, estão (5), que introduz uma conclusão e (6), que expressa desaprovação (também em jeito de conclusão) e (8) que expressa além de desaprovação, impaciência.

Mas (7) simplesmente preenche uma pausa na fala e (9) parece simplesmente um reconhecimento de um facto. Como, de resto, o Jacinto menciona na sua resposta, esse reconhecimento pode mesmo ser uma anuência reticente:

> (10) *- Vou sair com os meus amigos. - Bom, vê lá se não chegas tarde.*

Uma forma mais neutra de anuir seria usar "muito bem", que por isso já precisa mais de um "mas" para expressar reservas (e que mesmo assim não soa tão irritadiço como a frase com "bom"):

> (11) *- Vou sair com os meus amigos. - Muito bem, mas vê lá se não chegas tarde.*

Disse que "bem" era sinónimo, mas os significado não é exatamente o mesmo. "Bom" é mais agressivo, mais brusco do que bem. Consequentemente, é mais fácil expressar desaprovação ou impaciência com "bom" do que com "bem". Repare-se que existe a expressão "bom, bom" (como em (8), mas que pode até expressar uma ameaça), mas não "bem, bem".

Comment: "vê lá" é uma locução interessante.  Qual terá sido a origem?  "vê lá"  o que e onde?

Comment: Na definição 22 do Aulete só usamos "bem".  Raramente "bom"

Comment: @Centaurus O "lá" não há de ser literal aí, tal como em "sei lá". Mas acho que há aí material para uma pergunta :)

Answer (score 2):

A definição da [interjeição **bom** no Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/boa) para mim está praticamente diametralmente errada. A de **boa** está correta. Vou transcrever a definição do Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, que corresponde ao meu entendimento:

> **Bom**
>   **1** Exclamação que exprime descontentamento. *Bom! Não insistas, já disse o que tinha a dizer! Bom, Bom! já não estou a gostar nada disso!*
>   **2** Exclamação que introduz enunciados no discurso oral. *Bom! Vamos lá embora. Bom! O que é que eu estava a dizer?*

Na minha experiência, **bom** pode ainda introduzir um consentimento renitente ou cético:

> "Mãe, deixa-me lá ir. Eu prometo que estou em casa da meia noite." – "Bom! Então está bem. Mas olha que é mesmo para estares em casa antes da meia noite!"

**Bom** é em todos estes sentidos substituível por **bem**. É claro que com as interjeições a entoação conta muito. E com a entoação apropriada poderia conseguir-se exprimir aprovação com *bom*. Mas os usos acima é que são os típicos.

Sobre **boa** não há dúvida: serve para exprimir aprovação e agrado com entusiasmo:

> "Passei com nota máxima!" – "Boa! Assim mesmo é que é!"