# Qual foi a origem do significado da interjeição «boa»?

Tags: origem-histórica, interjeições

[Noutra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1334/112) foi esclarecido que a interjeição «boa» exprime aprovação, mas que nem «bom» nem «bem» têm este significado.

Como é que aconteceu, historicamente, que «boa» foi escolhida para isso?

Comment: Pois, que coisa é «boa»? Difícil de dizer. Há muitas outras frases onde há um elemento no feminino e onde não é claro a que é que se referem: «ora essa!», «essa é boa», «há com cada uma», «não há duas sem três», ...

Answer (score -1):

A expressão "boa" foi adotada *informalmente* para exprimir aprovação sobre algo, tendo certa diferença de "bom" e "bem". Exemplo:

```
 - Você faria o relatório pra mim, por favor?
 - Sim, já o fiz, aqui está
 - Boa!! Obrigado
```

Logo, a origem desta forma de expressão tem raízes populares e baseia-se no informalismo corriqueiro

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que "boa" venha de "boa ideia!".

Como interjeições costumam ser curtas, "boa ideia" foi encurtada para apenas "boa!". Com o uso, "boa" passou a ter outros significados que não se traduzem necessariamente em "boa ideia", mas ainda contêm o sentido de uma surpresa agradável na interação com outra pessoa.

Infelizmente não sei como confirmar essa teoria com referências, mas os exemplos mais comuns que consigo levam a essa teoria.

```
- Trouxe alguns livros para este fim de semana.
- Boa [ideia]!

- Troquei as lâmpadas por algumas mais fortes.
- Boa [ideia]!
```

No o exemplo da resposta anterior:

```
- Você faria o relatório pra mim, por favor?
- Sim, já o fiz, aqui está
- Boa!! Obrigado
```

É possível interpretar como "boa ideia, essa de adiantar o relatório".

Apesar de possível, eu não acho comum usar "boa" quando não há interação com outras pessoas. Por exemplo, se alguém consegue resolver um problema difícil, há interjeições mais usadas do que "boa".

E também acho incomum usar a interjeição quando não há ideias novas envolvidas. Por exemplo, acho que o diálogo abaixo soa estranho.

```
- Como estamos na lua cheia hoje, a pescaria deve render.
- Boa!
```

Note sempre que a interjeição "boa" só é utilizada em contextos informais.